# Can I obtain the most popular sub-reddits during a specified time frame using Reddit API PRAW?

Tags: reddit, praw

Let's say I need to obtain the text (post and all comments) from the sub-reddits that were most popular during December 2014 and January 2015. How can that be done using PRAW? I was wondering, just like Twitter doesn't let us crawl tweets which are more than a week old, is there any such time constraint in place in case of Reddit?

Answer (score 1):

PRAW has a limit of 1,000 for how far back you can get threads from a subreddit based on score, newness, "hotness" (I'm not sure if that one still works) or "controversy" (I haven't tried that one in a while, as well).  Unfortunately, the most popular subreddits have had too many posts to look that far back.

You can try using `search()` [http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.**init**.UnauthenticatedReddit.search](http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.UnauthenticatedReddit.search) to get the values you want, but it requires a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I will accept this answer if I don't get any better answer in the next few days.